# Oracle to Apache Cassandra data migration

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am working on an Apache Cassandra data migration. I have couple of tables which I need to move to the Cassandra column family with data - what is the best way to do this?

I have seen Apache Sqoop, will it help me? If yes, then what are the steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no silver bullet to migrate data from Oracle (or any RDBMS) to Cassandra. The way your data is modeled in Cassandra is fundamentally different from a relation database schema. Tools might help you to some degree, but you'll first have to create a new data model that will match the way you're going to read and write data into Cassandra. This article gives you a good start with Cassandra data modeling: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling